# UI freezes on tableview reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, reloaddata

I have simple dictionary project with over 35000 records in Realm model. When searching word from these records looking a little bit freeze in keyboard tapping. I think freeze going when I update my tableview with new records.

```swift
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var myRealmObject: Results<MyRealmObject>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myRealmObject = realm.objects(MyRealmObject.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "german", ascending: true)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myRealmObject.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = myRealmObject[indexPath.row].german
        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        myRealmObject = realm.objects(MyRealmObject.self).filter("german beginswith[cd] %@", searchText)
        print("Objects count - ", myRealmObject.count)
//        self.tableView.performSelector(onMainThread: Selector("reloadData"), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

If comment self.tableView.reloadData() and print result of Realm objects in console working without freezes. How I can perform my tableview.reload Data() ?

Comment: Is your `IBOutlet` connected? What do you mean by "freezing"? The app stops with an exception? What does the console say?

Comment: For one thing, calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` when you are already on the main thread is pointless and gums up the works.

Comment: @Alejandro Iván IBOutlet connected. when tapping on keyboard for searching 0.2-0.6 sec freezed keyboard then update tableview

Comment: @matt without DispatchQueue.main.async problem is relevant. Do you have any suggestion for perform tableview.reloadData ?

Comment: @matt DispatchQueue.main.async it's not get main queue asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard is freezing coz you are performing filter on main thread which is taking time to operate on 35000 objects..As per my understanding, you need to put the below line in a background thread or use GCD to execute it asynchronously

```
 myRealmObject = realm.objects(MyRealmObject.self).filter("german beginswith[cd] %@", searchText)
```

Create a serial queue

```
private let serialQueue =
  DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.searchQueue", attributes: .serial)
```

and then use the below code in your `textDidChange`

```
serialQueue.async { [weak self] in
  guard let self = self else {
    return
  }
  // put your filter logic in here
  //self.myRealmObject = self.realm.objects(MyRealmObject.self).filter("german beginswith[cd] %@", searchText)

  DispatchQueue.main.sync { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

However, there is something more that you need to consider. When user is typing real fast, it is worthwhile considering cancelling previous tasks before starting a new one or probably use `asyncAfter`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However with your suggestion continue freezing keyboard. I change a little bit your code: